# F* Raising Exception in match body

Tags: exception, fstar

I am trying to create a function in F* to determine the minimum element of a list, and I want to throw an exception if the list is empty. The code I have so far is below:

```
module MinList

exception EmptyList

val min_list: list int -> Exn int
let rec min_list l = match l with
  | [] -> raise EmptyList
  | single_el :: [] -> single_el
  | hd :: tl -> min hd (min_list tl)
```

When I try to verify the file, however, I get the following error:

```
mcve.fst(7,10-7,15): (Error 72) Identifier not found: [raise]
1 error was reported (see above)
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error comes up because `raise` is not a primitive in F* but needs to be imported from `FStar.Exn` (see [ulib/FStar.Exn.fst](https://github.com/FStarLang/FStar/blob/master/ulib/FStar.Exn.fst)), which exposes this function -- `raise`. Simply `open`ing this module should be sufficient. There is one more minor issue in the code that I have also fixed below.

Here's the version of the code that goes through:

```
module MinList

open FStar.Exn

exception EmptyList

val min_list: list int -> Exn int (requires True) (ensures (fun _ -> True))
let rec min_list l = match l with
  | [] -> raise EmptyList
  | single_el :: [] -> single_el
  | hd :: tl -> min hd (min_list tl)
```

Notice that I also have added `requires` and `ensures` clauses. This is because the `Exn` effect *expects* a these clauses to reason about the code in it. If your use case however, has exactly the above clauses (i.e., true and true), then you can use the convenient synonym for this, `Ex` (see [ulib/FStar.Pervasives.fst](https://github.com/FStarLang/FStar/blob/master/ulib/FStar.Pervasives.fst#L153)). Thus, the following code is also valid and will behave *exactly* the same as the above code.

```
module MinList

open FStar.Exn

exception EmptyList

val min_list: list int -> Ex int
let rec min_list l = match l with
  | [] -> raise EmptyList
  | single_el :: [] -> single_el
  | hd :: tl -> min hd (min_list tl)
```

Comment: Just to clarify: in the clause `(ensures (fun _ -> True))`, where is `fun` defined, and what value does it take?

Comment: `fun` is syntax that is built into F* to define anonymous functions. Here, `fun _ -> True` defines an anonymous function that takes one argument, and ignores it (the `_` part), and then returns `True`).

This is equivalent to anonymous functions in other languages like OCaml. Some languages prefer to call them "lambda"s.